# How to select the parent element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="c-wrapper c-sidebar-fixed">
    <div class="c-sidebar">
        Side Bar Menu
    </div>
</div>
```

The current CSS code was designed when the side bar div was outside of the c-wrapper. Now I moved the sidebar inside of wrapper. How this CSS can be adjusted to work with the current html structure?

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html:not([dir="rtl"]) .c-sidebar.c-sidebar-fixed ~ .c-wrapper {
    margin-left: 256px;
  }
  *[dir="rtl"] .c-sidebar.c-sidebar-fixed ~ .c-wrapper {
    margin-right: 256px;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the most efficient way to select the parent element `c-wrapper`. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: @DBS Thanks for clarification. Is there alternative solution for this situation?

Comment: you would need to apply the fixed class directly to the parent or just have the margin left on the child - shouldn't make any difference unless there are other things in the wrapper

Comment: @Pete Can you provide example? Thank you.

Comment: not really - you haven't shown what adds the class

Comment: @Pete What class? The css will apply based on the media query.

Comment: `c-sidebar-fixed` - that class doesn't exist in your html

Comment: @Pete Now exists.